# Mark Source root and test root in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

First I imported a project using Maven. After that I observed that source root and destination roots are not marked by default.

One option is to configure them manually using `Mark directory as Source/Test root`, but I have a lot of Maven modules.

Is there any other way to change this ?

Answer (score 0):

If the projects respectively the modules which you want to import are proper structured Maven projects, you can go this way:

1. Menu "File"
2. Function "New" --> "Project from existing sources..."
3. choose folder which contains the `pom.xml`, or the `pom.xml` itself
   [image]
4. next dialog:
   [image]
5. next dialog:
   [image]
6. finally, choose a place on your disk and a project name

After these steps, you get a proper Maven-IntelliJ project.